# Determine numerically centrum of symmetry of sampled function

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, numerical-optimization, numerical-calculus

I have a samped function $f$ represented as a vector `f` of length `N`, which shall be approximately even/symmetric with respect to particular unknown index `I` $$I \in [0 \ldots N-1]$$ so that

```
f[I+i]-f[I-i] \approx 0 with respect to admissible i's
```

I know `I` shall be somewhere around the center of x axis e.g. $N/2 \pm 0.1N$ .
The problem is my sampled `f` contains noise and may be biased towards the tails.

In the following graph I plot one realization of `f` and its flipped version
[image: Approximatelly symmetric function]

The best I did so far is trying to iteratively sum `f` with its flipped shifted version and find the minimum

```
import numpy as np
ff = -np.flip(f)
IND = np.arange(-100,100)
J = IND[np.argmin([np.linalg.norm(f+ np.roll(ff,i)) for i in IND])]
print("Minimum is at shift I = %f."%(N/2 - J/2))
```

I can not rely on argmax as there don't need to be the peak. I would like to find $I$ that is resistant to the noise in tails and more sensitive to the center of the `f`.

There might be some discrete FFT based methods, but I did not managed to get one working. What are your suggestions to address this problem?